# Using time picker as timer?

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-view, timepicker

Is there anyway to use the timepicker as timer ... like if the user picks 1hour 30mins on the timepicker it will set the alarm one hour 30 mins from now and not at like 1.30am in the morning?  also is there anyway of getting rid of the timepicker title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anyway to use the `TimePicker` as timer... like if the user picks 1:30 on the `TimePicker` it will set the alarm one hour and 30 mins from now?

The `TimePicker` displays times, not quantities. You could interpret the time in this way, if you really wanted, but it wouldn't be very useful if the user wanted to set the alarm, say, 25 hours from now.

I would suggest you implement your own `View` instead (or Google search for one that has already been made).

> Is there anyway of getting rid of the timepicker title?

If you mean the `TimePickerDialog`, then yes. You can call [`setTitle(CharSequence title)`](http://tinyurl.com/ccswlcp).

---

### Edit:

In a comment, you asked,

> How do I prevent the title from auto-updating when I change the time?

Take a look at the [source code](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/TimePickerDialog.java) and you'll find that the `onTimeChanged` method will update the title like this by default. To prevent the title from being updated, you'll need to implement a `TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener`,

```
private OnTimeChangedListener mListener = new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
    @Override      
    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // do nothing when time is changed
    }
};
```

Then pass this listener to the [constructor](http://tinyurl.com/cswq5u9) when you instantiate the `TimePickerDialog`.

Comment: yea timepicker will do as timer i only allow user to set it to a max of 5 hours since it only be quick alarm i need.

Comment: one more thing ... i can change title of timepicker using  setTitle(CharSequence title) but when i change the time it sets the time as the title and gets rid of my title how do i stop this?

Comment: See my updated post. I haven't tested any of it... I figured out most of it from looking at the source code (this can be a very useful tool).

Comment: sorry again ... but only problem i have is setting listner in timepicker i use timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(); in timepickerdialog to connect it but it said it is undefined in timepickerdialog?

Comment: That's because there is no `setOnTimeChangedListener` method for `TimePickerDialog`. That's why you have to pass it to the constructor instead.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answers (for all 3 of the `TimePicker` questions you asked). You can do so by clicking the check next to the most helpful answer.